# java.io.EOFException when trying to perform java socket operations

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I'm getting the following exception for the code included below that. **This works fine when the while() loop is excluded**. Why is this?

```
Oct 6, 2011 1:19:31 AM com.mytunes.server.ServerHandler run
SEVERE: null
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2552)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1297)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
    at com.mytunes.server.ServerHandler.run(ServerHandler.java:68)
```

Class ServerHandler:

```
public class ServerHandler extends Thread {
 .
 .
 .

public ServerHandler(...){
...
}


public void run(){

    try {

        os = s.getOutputStream();
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);

        is = s.getInputStream();
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);

        while(true){

            msg = (Messenger) ois.readObject(); 

            String methodType = msg.getKey();

            //validating various data passed from the serialized object
            if(methodType.equals("validateCard")){

            } else if(methodType.equals("validatePIN")){

            }

        }

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally{
        try {
            ois.close();
            is.close();
            oos.close();
            os.close();
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }



}
```

}

Class Server

```
public class Server{

    ...
    ServerSocket ss;
    ...

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Server server = new Server();
       server.init();

    }

    public void init(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Server started...");

            ss = new ServerSocket(port);

             System.out.println("Listening on " + ss.getInetAddress() + ":" + ss.getLocalPort());

            System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");

            while(true){
                  Socket incoming_socket = ss.accept(); // returns a Socket connection object if received
                  new ServerHandler(...).start();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You keep trying to read objects *forever*, never breaking out of the loop. When the client closes the connection, the stream will run out of data, and the `ObjectInputStream.readObject` method will throw the exception you're seeing.

How many objects did you expect to be in the stream, and why are you reading past the end of them?

Comment: +1 for the quick reply! what i want to do is this: each client will initiate new socket connections with the Server. while **being inside that** connection, i want the client to communicate (two-way) with the Server as I thought connecting-and-disconneting repeatedly is unnecessary. Is it a bad practice? Does the **Client** always need to close the socket,ois,is,oos,os ?

Comment: @coder9: It's generally fine to do that sort of communication, but you'll probably need to know when to stop... it's not clear to me that `ObjectInputStream` gives you that information easily. (I should warn you that Java binary serialization is generally problematic in various ways - I'd consider something like Protocol Buffers if I were you.)

Comment: Maybe I should stick with this for now since this is only for an academic assignment :) thanks.

Comment: @Jon:How is it possible to know so much on Java and still not be your main language?(I have seen you are into C#).I am struggling just to be good in 1 language.How do you do this?(Always asking to find ways to improve myself).

Comment: @user384706: Spending a fair amount of time here helps - and although I *love* C#, Java is the one I use professionally. I'm just an enthusiastic amateur at C# :)

Comment: @user384706: As I believe, once you grasp the basics of any language like C/C++ you can take any language as easy to master on.I'm also a newbie in Java and found its so cool! I owe the guys here at stackoverflow a LOT! cheers! :)