# Java streams with EOFException

Tags: java, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream, eofexception

I wrote some client - server program, that shares data but at server side i got `EOFException` after reciving data. I tried to fix it on my own but it is hard to find own errors.

The error is caused by this line: `Message command =(Message) serInputStream.readObject();`

Here is some output from server:

```
 java.io.EOFException

at Java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2577)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
at transfer.Serwerus.run(Serwerus.java:42)
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Serwerus implements Runnable
{
public InputStream is;
public FileOutputStream fos;
public BufferedOutputStream bos;
public ObjectOutputStream serOutputStream;
public ObjectInputStream serInputStream;
ServerSocket socket;
private String clientMessage, clientFileName;
private int clientFileSize;

public Serwerus()
{
    try
    {
        socket = new ServerSocket(6060);
        System.out.println("Server started....");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try 
        {
            Socket sock = socket.accept();
            System.out.println("Client accepted");
            serOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            serInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
          while (true) 
          {
              Message command =(Message) serInputStream.readObject();
              System.out.println("after readObject");
              if (command.getCommand().startsWith("FileU")) 
              {
                  System.out.println("Name = " + command.getfileName() + ", size= " + command.getfileSize());
                  serOutputStream.writeObject(new Message("Bring", "", 0));
                  //ReciveData(socket, command.getfileName(), command.getfileSize());
              }
              else if(command.getCommand().startsWith("Wait"))
              {
                  System.out.println("hohoho");
                  ReciveData(sock, command.getfileName(), command.getfileSize());
              }
              else if(command.getCommand().startsWith("Quit"))
              {
                  System.exit(1);
              }
              else
              {
                  System.out.println("Unknow");
              }
          }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally 
        {
            try 
            {
                serInputStream.close();
                serOutputStream.close();
                socket.close();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.err.println("Fallen on closing socket.\n Error: " + e);
            }
        }
}

public void SendData(Socket sock, String filePath) throws Exception
{
    File myFile = new File (filePath);
    System.out.println("File name = " + myFile.getName() + " File len = " + (int)myFile.length());
    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
    System.out.println("Sending...");
    os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
    os.flush();
    sock.close();
    System.out.println("Sending finished");
}

public void ReciveData(Socket sock, String filePath, int fileSize)
{
    System.out.println("Recive in progress, filesize = " + fileSize);
    int bytesRead = 0, current = 0;
    byte[] array = new byte[fileSize];

    try 
    {

        is = sock.getInputStream();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        do
        {
            System.out.println(bytesRead);
            bytesRead = is.read(array);
            current += bytesRead;
        }
        while(bytesRead > -1);

        bos.write(array, 0 , current);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        fos.close();
       // sock.close();
        System.out.println("Reciveing finished");
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException 
 {
     new Thread(new Serwerus()).start(); 
 }
}
```

Client code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Clientus implements Runnable
{
    InputStream is;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedOutputStream bos;
    ObjectOutputStream cliOutputStream;
    ObjectInputStream cliInputStream;
    Socket socket;
    File actFile;
    private String serverMessage, serverFileName;
    private int serverFileSize;

    public Clientus()
    {
        try 
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 6060);
            cliOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            cliInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            File file = new File(<filepath>);
            actFile = file;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try 
            {   
                cliOutputStream.writeObject(new Message("FileU", actFile.getPath(), (int) actFile.length()));
                cliOutputStream.flush();
              //while (true) 
              //{
                  Message command =(Message) cliInputStream.readObject();
                  if (command.getCommand().startsWith("File")) 
                  {
                      String name = command.getfileName();
                      int size = command.getfileSize();
                      System.out.println("Name = " + command.getfileName() + ", size= " + command.getfileSize());
                      if(size != 0 && !"".equals(name))
                      {
                          //ReciveData(socket, 0);
                      }
                  }
                  else if(command.getCommand().startsWith("Bring"))
                  {
                      cliOutputStream.writeObject(new Message("Wait", "D:\\KP2\\Serwer\\dupa.txt",(int) actFile.length()));
                      cliOutputStream.flush();
                      try 
                      {
                          SendData(socket, actFile.getPath());
                          //this.socket.close();
                      } 
                      catch (Exception ex) 
                      {
                         System.err.println("Error with: SendData()");
                      }
                  }
                  else if(command.getCommand().startsWith("Quit"))
                  {
                      System.exit(1);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      System.out.println("Command unknown");
                  }
              //}
            }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally 
            {
                try 
                {
                    socket.close();
                    cliOutputStream.close();
                    cliInputStream.close();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    System.err.println("Fallen on closing socket.\n Error: " + e);
                }
            }
    }

    public void SendData(Socket sock, String filePath) throws Exception
    {
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int) new File(filePath).length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        System.out.println("Sending...");
        os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
        fis.close();
        bis.close();
        os.close();
        System.out.println("Sending finished");
    }

    public void ReciveData(Socket sock, String fileName, int fileSize)
    {
        int bytesRead, current = 0;
        byte[] array = new byte[fileSize+1];
        try 
        {
            is = sock.getInputStream();
            fos = new FileOutputStream(<file_path>);

            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(array,0,array.length);

            current = bytesRead;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = is.read(array, current, (array.length - current));
                if(bytesRead >= 0)
                    current += bytesRead;
            }
            while(bytesRead > -1);

            bos.write(array, 0 , current);
            bos.flush();

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            //System.out.println("Send time: " + (end - start));
            bos.close();
            sock.close();
            System.out.println("Reciveing finished");
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException 
    {
        new Thread(new Clientus()).start();
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please specify the `Exception` refers to which line of your program.

Comment: Maybe this question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/10858195/2115680

Comment: @boomz I suspect that the line in question is `Message command =(Message) serInputStream.readObject();`

Comment: @boomz Exception is specified to server program at line #42

Comment: @Marc-Andre Just right there

Comment: I think it's the same.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666997/java-io-eofexception-when-trying-to-perform-java-socket-operations

Comment: @user1721713 Yes it looks similary, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your client may be disconnected after sending data and because your server is waiting for more data, the `EOFException` will occurr.

To fix this problem, you can add `try-catch` block to catching this exception when the client disconnects.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using both the `ObjectOutputStream` and the socket's own `OutputStream` to send data on, and you are getting out of sync. When you send the raw data directly over the socket you aren't sending the length first, so the receiver doesn't know how many bytes belong to this transmission. In fact it just reads everything until EOS, so next time you call `ObjectInputStream.readObject()` it naturally gets an EOFException. To fix this:

1. Use the `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for *everything*.
2. Before sending the file, send its length, via `writeLong().`
3. At the receiver, when receiving the file, first get its length, via `readLong(),` then read exactly that many bytes from the `ObjectInputStream` and copy them to the file.